# How can i combat with java update on mac snow leopard

Tags: java, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I am using preinstalled jdk for development on mac which is 1.6.0_17. With this version or copy if installed jdk i cannot run java applets in firefox or any other web browser on mac. if i update my mac with latest java which is [Java for mac OS X 10.6 update 6](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1360) then i can solve java applet. But with latest java update i cannot connect to MSSQL Server which is [bug in java 1.6.0_29](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7105007). I would be happy to install older version of java for mac OS X but those are not available, may be i am unable to find them through google ?

My query is, how can i solve both problems ? can i install two java versions on mac and use them parallely, lets say one for eclipse and other for browser. OR is there any other way to cope both problems.

I am using current snow leopard, myEclipse, Java 1.6.0_17 and mssql server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not solved it 100% but some how solution or workaround works. Which is working with two javas

1. Java for mac osx
2. OpenJDK for development

So i have updated my mac with latest java version that i can easily use java applet.Later i have downloaded and configured openjdk for development.

if you are using mac then perhaps this link would be more helpful .

- [1]: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/macosx-port/
- [2]: http://code.google.com/p/openjdk-osx-build/

Simply make a folder "javaVirutalMachines" under "/Library/java/" and double click on alreadly download build file of openjdk. **

Answer (score 2):

The bug that causes the JDBC driver to fail is fixed in java 1.6.0_30 - see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u30-relnotes-1394870.html

---

If you can't wait for update 30 for the Mac to arrive, the bug description suggests that you may be able to avoid it by reconfiguring your the JDBC connection to use a non-SSL/TLS channel.  (I've no idea how you'd do that, but it is worth investigating if you are desperate for a workaround.)

Alternatively talk to Apple or Oracle's Java support.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Surely i can see in attached hyperlink that this bug is fixed in update 30  but there is not any java update for mac osx.Or do you have any idea how can merge those fixes in 1.6_29 without waiting for java update from apple.